# Knoct out template binding - changing datasource at runtime and rebind template

Tags: templates, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```js
<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
 <tr><td>
       <p>Book Title: <h3 data-bind="text: Title"></h3>       
       <p>Available City: <span data-bind="text: CityName"></span></p>
</td></tr>
</script>
 



jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
      
        var loData = AjaxCall('default.aspx', 'GetBookData', '10');
        var Data = JSON.parse(loData.Data);
 
        function MyViewModel() {
            this.people = Data.Table
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel()); 
       
    });
 
 
 $("#btnChangData").click(
 
        var loData = AjaxCall('default.aspx', 'GetBookData', '20');
        var Data = JSON.parse(loData.Data);           
        
        ko.cleanNode($("#list")[0]);
        $('#sample').empty();
        $('#sample').html('<tbody id="list" data-bind="template: { name: "person-template", foreach: people }" ></tbody>');
        function MyViewModel() {
            this.people = Data.Table
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
  
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<table id="sample">     
<tbody id="list" data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', foreach: people }" >
</tbody>                                
</table>
```

I have load data on document ready function to table. but in button click event i need to load new datasource to table, how can rebind datasource to knockout template.. in click event above code throws
Hide   Copy Code
You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element
error on console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
i have tried below code and its worked for me, i have declare viewmodel globally

var vm; 
var viewModel = function () { 
var self = this; 
this.people = ko.observableArray([]); 
this.updatedata = function (data) { ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.people); } };

and on page load 
vm = new viewModel(); vm.updatedata(Data.Table); ko.applyBindings(vm); 

and for data update vm.updatedata(Data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Knockout. Now please stop writing jQuery.

You do not need to create a new viewmodel every time your data changes. Your viewmodel is intended to model your entire application. You create and bind it once.

Your table should be an observable, which is a setter-getter function that is the foundation of Knockout. To assign new data to it, you pass it the new data:

```
viewmodel.people(Data.table)
```

If you have not been through the [Knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com), you should do that. Knockout is easier than you're making it.

Update: Your JavaScript should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var loData = AjaxCall('default.aspx', 'GetBookData', '10');
  var Data = JSON.parse(loData.Data);

  function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.people = Data.Table;
    this.changeData = function() {
      var loData = AjaxCall('default.aspx', 'GetBookData', '20');
      var Data = JSON.parse(loData.Data);
      self.people(Data.Table);
    };
  }
  ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

});
```

Comment: Globally declared  var viewModel = {
        people: ko.observableArray([])
    }
on Pageload :
 viewModel.people = Data.Table;        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

on clickevent : var Data = JSON.parse(loData.Data);            
        
        viewModel.people(Data.table);   On page load its binded correctly but on click event i have update viewmodel people data's are update but still html not binded with new data's

Comment: Don't reassign `viewModel.people`, set its contents: `viewModel.people(Data.Table)`

Comment: i did that , but still html not rebinded

Comment: Thans for your support Roy J, i have tried below code and its worked for me, i have declare viewmodel globally var vm;
    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.people = ko.observableArray([]);    
        this.updatedata = function (data) {
             ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.people);
        }        
    };  and   on page load  vm = new viewModel();
        vm.updatedata(Data.Table);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);  and for data update  vm.updatedata(Data)